# Unable to get the local directory referenced to docker

Tags: c#, linux, docker

I have a console application published in linux, the application reads the data from a particular directory in Linux. so if I want to run the console application, I would do the below

```
./myapp "/home/user1/mydata"
```

Files in **mydata** directory will be changing. It all works fine when I run the application directly in the Linux terminal.
But when I dockerize the application, I am unable to read the directory "/home/user1/mydata".

Below is Dockerfile contents

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["./myapp"]
```

my intention is when I run the docker image, I will also the include path of the directory

for example

```
docker run myimage:latest "/home/user1/mydata"
```

I understand that in order to read the directory, I need first mount the directory, so I created a volume

```
docker volume create myvolume
```

and then mounted my target directory

```
docker run -t -d -v my-vol:/home/user1/mydata --name mycontainer myimage:latest
```

even after mounting when I am running the docker as

```
docker run myimage:latest "/home/user1/mydata"
```

It is still unable to read the directory. Am I doing something wrong here ? After mounting the directory do I have to change the way I call my argument in this case /home/user1/mydata ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker volume create myvolume` will create a folder in docker system location, while `-v my-vol:/home/user1/mydata` will pop the `/home/user1/mydata` in container to that docker host's system location, typically `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

So, for your case, you need to use [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), not [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), something like next:

```
docker run -t -d -v /home/user1/mydata:/home/user1/mydata --name mycontainer myimage:latest "/home/user1/mydata"
```

`-v /home/user1/mydata:/home/user1/mydata` will mount the folder `/home/user1/mydata` on docker host to container's `/home/user1/mydata`, so this I guess could meet your requirement.